# Filter on latest document of each group in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's assume that the following documents are indexed in Elasticsearch:

```
{student: "Chloe", date: "2016-10-27", grade: "A"}
{student: "Oliver", date: "2016-10-27", grade: "F"}
{student: "Chloe", date: "2016-10-26", grade: "B"}
{student: "Chloe", date: "2016-10-25", grade: "F"}
{student: "Oliver", date: "2016-10-25", grade: "A"}
```

I can use top hits aggregation to get a list of students with latest grade:

```
{student: "Chloe", date: "2016-10-27", grade: "A"}
{student: "Oliver", date: "2016-10-27", grade: "F"}
```

But how can I get a list of students whose latest grade is "F" (only student with name "Oliver" in this particular example)? For example, expected result is:

```
{student: "Oliver", date: "2016-10-27", grade: "F"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A query_string cannot works in your case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)(**Only ES 2.x**). I am basically comparing max date of each student with max date when they got F grade([filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)) and only retaining results where both dates are same. You can remove [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) if you want, it is just there to get that particular record where student failed.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_students": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "student"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "only_f_grade_bucket": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "grade": "F"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_date": {
              "max": {
                "field": "date"
              }
            },
            "top_hit":{
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "latest_failure": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "failed_date": "only_f_grade_bucket.latest_date",
              "max_date": "max_date"
            },
            "script": "failed_date == max_date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Your `top_hit` aggregation assumes the documents are always indexed in descending date order. Replace it with the following to make sure the top hit is the most recent: `"top_hits": {"size": 1, "sort": [{"date": {"order": "desc"}}]}`